# kubernetes nginx ingress 80, 443, 10443

Tags: nginx

In a kubernetes cluster, I am using nginx ingress as a loadbalancer and I would like to access some of my services on 80, 443, but also 10443(for example).

Is this possible with nginx ingress? or do you have an alternative solution for what I am trying to do?